# Unable to call Angular Directiive Method on Button Click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to call directive method on button click from the calling controller.

Here is the directive code:

```
  myApp.directive("helloDirective", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: '<input type="text" data-ng-model="model.msg" />',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        param: "="
      },
      controller: 'helloDirectiveController',
      controllerAs: 'model'
    }
  })
  .controller("helloDirectiveController", function() {
      var self = this;
      self.actions = {
        get: function() {
          return self.msg;
        },
        set: function(msgData) {
          self.msg = msgData;
        }
      });
```

I have call the `get` and `set` method from controller..

```
myApp.controller("indexController", [function() {
    var self = this;
    self.helloParam ={};
    self.get = function() {
      //how to call the Directive get method from here
    }
  }]);
```

i tried to create a fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ya6pobj8/29/)

[**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FonjZkfz5LfgHPkvIBXl?p=preview)

Comment: Yor fiddle is not at all working. Please make a plunker instead of fiddle?

Comment: Do you want to call the method in directive's controller from `indexController`?

Comment: yes, i comment the place where i want to call that method.@Mr_Perfect

Comment: That means you want to call a method that is in child controller from the parent's controller. That is not possible. You can call one directive's controller method from another directive's controller

Comment: There is a workaround for that. I will try to prepare a code sample in a while

Comment: yes, it's possible. @Mr_Perfect

Comment: I've added an answer with solution which for me seems pretty clean and comfortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Change The Directive Code, moved `Controller` code to `link` and it's working fine.

```
testApp.directive("helloDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<input type="text" data-ng-model="model.msg" />',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            param: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var self = scope.model;

            var assignMethod = function () {
                if (self.param == undefined) {
                    self.param = {};
                }
                self.param.actions = {
                    get: function () {
                        return self.msg;
                    },
                    set: function (msgData) {
                        self.msg = msgData;
                    }
                };
            };
            assignMethod();
        },
        controller: function () { },
        controllerAs: 'model'
    }
});
```

now i can call the directive get Method from calling controller like,

```
  self.helloParam = {};

  self.click = function () {
        alert(self.helloParam.actions.get());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**The idea**

For me, the cleanest solution (so far) for your problem is a solution used by Angular Material developers (I don't know if they were the authors, but I found it there). I've used it once in my project and it worked like a charm.

The idea is to create a global registry for directives' actions. Directives would be stored there by unique ids. We can also create a service dedicated for each directive, just in case we need some external logic.

**The solution**

*1. Components registry*

Firstly, we need a components registry. It can be a really simple service:

```
angular.module('app');
    .service('$componentsRegistry', function() {
        var self = this;
        var components = {};

        self.put = function(id, actions) {
            components[id] = actions;
        }

        self.get = function(id) {
            return components[id];
        }
    })
```

The components registry has methods for storing and getting components by ids. Of course, there might be much more methods and they might be more complicated, but this is just a simple example.

*2. Service for our directive*

Let's say we have a simple `show-message` directive, so we can create a `$showMessageService`:

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('$showMessageService', ['$componentsRegistry', function($componentsRegistry) {
        return function(id) {
            return $componentsRegistry.get(id);
        }
    }])
```

For now, the only task of the service is to return our directive's actions. But it can be extended in the future, of course.

*3. Directive's code*

The last thing we need is our `show-message` directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('showMessage', function($componentsRegistry) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                directiveId: '@' // Unique id is passed from the view
            },
            template: '<div>{{ text }}</div>',
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.text = 'TEST TEXT';

                // Create actions
                scope.actions = {
                    set: function(value) {
                        scope.text = value;
                    }
                }    

                // Store actions in the components registry
                $componentsRegistry.put(scope.directiveId, scope.actions);
            }
        }
    })
```

In a link function, we need to simply register our actions in components registry. We pass the unique id from the view so that developer has control over it inside views/controllers.

---

**Example of usage**

And now we can finally use the directive in our application. Here is a simple code which shows how to do that:

*View*

```
<div ng-controller="testController as test">
    <show-message directive-id="testDirective"></show-message>
    <button ng-click="test.changeText()">CHANGE</button>
</div>
```

*Controller*

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('testController', function(['$showMessageService', $showMessageService) {
        var self = this;

        self.changeText = function() {
            $showMessageService('testDirective').set('NEW');
        }
    }])
```